# send parameters between single quotes in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
$c ='<img src="assets/img/share_fb.jpg" onclick="javascript:fbShare('.$data0["link"].','.$data0["title"].','.$data0["podcast"].','.$data0["image"].')" title="Facebook">';
?>
```

How can I send each value between single quotes?

Ex:

```
javascript:fbShare('www.123.com','page title','text','img/image1.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need quoted single quotes either side of your variables.

```
<?php
$c ='<img src="assets/img/share_fb.jpg" onclick="javascript:fbShare(\''.$data0["link"].'\',\''.$data0["title"].'\',\''.$data0["podcast"].'\',\''.$data0["image"].'\')" title="Facebook">';
?>
```